# Passwords stored in Paw file cannot be removed - How to make safe, sharable Paw file?

Tags: paw-app

I'd like to make a paw file that I can share with colleagues that has no passwords saved in it. It seems that no matter how I make the paw file, the password is embedded - not only in the requests, but in revision history. So I cannot test it with valid passwords, delete the password values, and then save a file that has no passwords.

I was hoping that using a file to store a value would accomplish what I want, but once the file is read, it seems to be embedded in the paw file. I can delete the source password file, and Paw still knows the secret password.

Is there a dynamic value that I should try? Is there some kind of session mode where I can be prompted for the password when I launch Paw?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**HTTP History (Requests / Responses) are not in .paw files**

The history of the requests and responses you sent and received that you can see in the right panel is never stored in your `.paw` files. Rather, it's stored in your library folder, as web browsers and other apps store caches or history data. So you should be safe for that part.

**Manually Remove Passwords**

You can manually remove passwords. This is bothering, but you can make things easier by using Environments. See [Environments](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Environments) and [Use Environments as Reusable Presets](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Environments_as_Reusable_Presets). This way your passwords are only in one place, and every request only points to that value. You can then remove just this value before sharing.

**Use Pawprint**

You can share your request with Pawprint, the service we made available to easily share requests and snap of history from Paw. If your password is in the `Authorization` header, it will be automatically hidden before sharing. In this case, the latest HTTP Exchange / History item will be shared too (with an hidden `Authorization` header).

*Future:* we plan to add full support for OS X Keychain (the Keychain Access app). This way, all passwords will be saved securely and outside your `.paw` files. It will allow you to safely share them with colleagues.

Comment: This is disappointing. Is there also no way to create environments that span multiple files? That would at least make it easy to maintain secret values in a file that's excluded from source control.

Comment: Paw 2.3 – which will be released in about a week – is bringing full encryption of your credentials. By default, credentials (such as passwords, secret keys) will be encrypted, but you can also explicitly encrypt a value. The encryption key will be stored in your Keychain, so you can share it with others if needed. Each value is encrypted by a derivate key (PBKDF2 key derivation). Though, no environments cannot span multiple files yet, it's another thing we'd like to add in the future.